# Latin phrase that means, dissolve and reintegrate

Tags: idiom, passage-identification

A couple of months ago, I heard this story of a demon or some entity that was cursed to eternally break something down and reintegrate it together. There is even a photo of the demon crying in the article where I read the story. The photo contains a Latin phrase meaning "dissolve and reintegrate", and I am looking for the exact Latin wording of this phrase. I can't remember why, but there is some connection to Pharmacy behind all of this. I think it means, breaking down a solution into it's constituents?

Also, the phrase has a philosophical meaning that if you are not able to understand something, break it down and try to understand the smaller parts, then the aggregate whole will start to make sense.

Comment: Sounds Greek:  Λυσις Ξυνθεσις.  Synthesis at least survives in English.

Comment: I found it, It's Solve et coagula @Hugh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, this is the state of play:

> Baphomet is a deity that the Knights Templar were falsely accused of
>   worshipping and that ... The arms bear the Latin words SOLVE
>   (separate) and COAGULA (join together) .

Wikipedia's article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baphomet).

Philosophers who described the world in such terms of continual change, and may have been sources for the demonology include:

**Heraclitus** "... then each object must dissolve and be generated continually momentarily ...... which synthesized."

**Cleanthes** (; Greek: Κλεάνθης Kleanthēs; c. 330 BC – c. 230 BC)

**Diogenes**